# Prettier is not formatting code at all in vscode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-vscode

I just cloned my job reactJs project that has following .prettierrc config in /src directory

```
{
"arrowParens": "avoid",
"bracketSpacing": true,
"endOfLine": "auto",
"jsxBracketSameLine": false,
"printWidth": 120,
"requirePragma": true,
"semi": true,
"singleQuote": true,
"tabWidth": 4,
"trailingComma": "all",
"lineLength": 120}
```

and my prettier now is not formatting my .js files at all. It ignores not only on save event also

```
shift + alt + f
```

I tried putting relative and absolute paths in config path field(in settings -> extensions -> prettier)
Maybe the problem is that my project has its backend next to frontend(Symfony). So I am not able to follow formatting rules of my project. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: default formatter is set to prettier. right click -> format document with-> configure -> prettier

Comment: have you installed the dependencies yet? either `npm install` or `yarn install` depending on which package manager your project uses

Comment: maybe i am specifiing path to .prettierrc in th wrong way... but formatting does not worl at all without it too

Comment: do i need to run npm install ? because i just tested it in other project( just new folder with only nodemon and body-parser in package.json) and it worked for it

Answer (score 0):

Go to VSCode settings, click on JSON add the following section if missing.

```
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
```

or try this..

```
{
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
  },
  "prettier.singleQuote": true
}
```

Comment: "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },

Comment: @RajeshKoothropali not sure why yours start with "[javascript]", edited the above lines

Comment: my prettierrc is not in the root directory. can this be a problem ?

Comment: tried "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Solarized Light", like this but same problem